# Google integation in windows phone 8.1[RT] application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, windows-phone-8.1, google-oauth

I am working with windows phone 8.1 application and I want to login with Google Plus , for that I have create Client id and Client secret from [Google](https://developers.google.com/)

```
 string uri = string.Format("{0}?response_type=code&client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&scope={3}&approval_prompt=force",
            authEndpoint,
            clientId,
            "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
            scope);
 webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute));
```

and I Got string something like `4/BGIl1Na3TQJlAD8SQ7blvHyONJ_Jyav8COHa7tIrAdo`

I want User Email and Name from account for signup or login 
Please help me for that.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the interafce IWebAuthenticationContinuable to your class and then under ContinueWebAuthentication() Method use this code :

```
var authData = GetGoogleSuccessCode(args.WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData); 
var userData = await GetTokenAndUserInfo(authData);

private string GetGoogleSuccessCode(string data)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) return null;
            var parts = data.Split('&')[0].Split('=');
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (parts[i] == "Success code")
                {
                    return parts[i + 1];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

public async Task<string> GetTokenAndUserInfo(string code)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var auth = await client.PostAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id",Constants.GoogleAppId), 
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret",Constants.GoogleAppSecret), 
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type","authorization_code"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri","urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"),  
                }));

            var data = await auth.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var j = JToken.Parse(data);
            var token = j.SelectToken("access_token");
            var searchUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.ToString());
            HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(searchUrl);
            string content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return content;
        }
```

And add following code in App.xaml.cs file:

```
public static ContinuationManager ContinuationManager { get; private set; }


 public App()
{
    ContinuationManager = new ContinuationManager();
}

private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            ContinuationManager.MarkAsStale();
#endif
            // TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
            deferral.Complete();
        }

protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
            if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuation)
            {
                var continuationEventArgs = args as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
                if (continuationEventArgs != null)
                {
                    ContinuationManager.Continue(continuationEventArgs);
                    ContinuationManager.MarkAsStale();
                }

            }
#endif
        }
```

Don't forget to include Continuation Manager class file in your project.
You will get the user info.

Comment: Hello Saurabh , Thank you for your answer . I have tried a lot for access_token , but it's work for me , can you have any reference or demo that I can find where I am wrong

Comment: Sorry I am not getting your problem. Are you not getting access_token for your app or you are facing some other problem? Can you explain the problem  in detail

Comment: I got :: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=-460212edee653c7e&hl=en_GB&pageId=none&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAVnfmNO_NLV1AbF5wqdi7xnsfWJuAzDXG "from args.WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData and  I got null from GetGoogleSuccessCode(args.WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData) becase there is no Success code

Comment: You got it from GetTokenAndUserInfo() Method??

Comment: I got it from args.WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData , ContinueWebAuthentication() method

Comment: Then pass that data into GetGoogleSuccessCode() method.Then you will get authData.Pass authData to GetTokenAndUserInfo(authData) method.You will get the desired result.I have already implemented it in my application.And it works like a charm.

Comment: I got your point , but I can't understand what is "Success code" in GetGoogleSuccessCode() method , because my data =  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=-460212edee653c7e&hl=en_GB&pageId=none&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAVnfmNO_NLV1AbF5wqdi7xnsfWJuAzDXG and there is no any field like sucess code , What I have to pass in sucess code

Comment: Send me your code so that i can understand what you are getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98565/discussion-between-saurabh-srivastava-and-kushal-maniyar).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert.

It looks like you need to request the email scope:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#login-scopes

as well as (probably) the profile scope (same page).

If this isn't helpful, please edit your question and show more of your code (obscuring your secret API key, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I have also searched for sign in using facebook and google in WIN RT Apps and finally found solution from this link :
[Web authentication broker sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)

Maybe it will help you also.

Comment: Thank you for you answer saurabh , but it will authenticate the user only.I want user detail after authenticate